# Differentiate between accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization

In my app there are different types of accounts like Free, Premium etc. Each type has a subset of features. What is the best way to restrict each account type type to only see those features what they are intended to see ? Can i use declarative authorization plugin and roles as Free, Premium etc or Is there any other plugin which is defined on feature set ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use cancan authorization library because its easy to use.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan